# convert bipartite graph to adjacency matrix python

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I'm trying to convert edge list which is in the following format

```
data = [('a', 'developer'),
         ('b', 'tester'),
        ('b', 'developer'),
         ('c','developer'),
         ('c', 'architect')]
```

where the adjacency matrix will be in the form of

```
      developer     tester    architect
a        1            0          0
b        1            1          0
c        1            0          1
```

I want to store the matrix in the following format

```
 1    0    0
 1    1    0
 1    0    1
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Post what you have tried already. [so] is not a code providing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done easily with [networkx](https://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/stable/):

```
from operator import itemgetter

import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.bipartite import biadjacency_matrix

def to_adjacency_matrix(data):
    g = nx.DiGraph()
    g.add_edges_from(data)
    partition_1 = set(map(itemgetter(0), data))
    return biadjacency_matrix(g, partition_1).toarray()
```